# Fire and forget in an Observable chain with RxJS

Tags: rxjs

Let's say I have 2 functions which return an Observable each

- `getUsersDataObs()`: the returned Observable calls an HTTP endpoint to get some data related to the user of the app, this Observable emits when the data is received
- `sendMailObs`: the returned Observable calls a mail server to send an email, this Observable emits when the mail server responds with an acknowledgment

I need the user data to create the mail, so I need to call first `getUsersDataObs` and then `sendMailObs`.  At the same time, I do not need to know whether `sendMailObs` has completed or not. I just want to send the mail with a "fire and forget" strategy.

The solution I have crafted so far is this

```
getUsersDataObs().pipe(
   tap(data => sendMailObs(data).subscribe())
)
.subscribe()
```

While this works, we have a subscription within a subscription, which usually is something that looks not so cool. At the same time, considering that what I want is "fire and forget", maybe a subscription within a subscription is the appropriate thing to do.

Comment: You could merge `sendMailObs(data)` to the chain and ignore all its emissions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing bad about this strategy unless you don't have to wait for `sendMailObs(data)` in order to incorporate its data. You can see `sendMailObs(data).subscribe()` as a side effect of `getUsersDataObs()`. Which indeed is the side effect in the given context.

Answer (score 0):

One of the downsides to subscriptions inside subscriptions is that it is really challenging to correctly unsubscribe from both. Consider instead using higher order mapping operators.

Something like this:

```
  selectedProductSuppliers$ = this.selectedProduct$
    .pipe(
      filter(selectedProduct => Boolean(selectedProduct)),
      switchMap(selectedProduct =>
        forkJoin(selectedProduct.supplierIds.map(supplierId => this.http.get<Supplier>(`${this.suppliersUrl}/${supplierId}`)))
      )
    );
```

When the first Observable (this.selectedProduct$) emits, it filters out any nulls (no product was selected). Then it uses switchMap (a higher-order mapping operator) to handle the inner subscription.

So your code would look something more like this:

```
getUsersDataObs().pipe(
   switchMap(data => sendMailObs(data))
)
.subscribe()
```

I have a stackblitz example that gets a user and then gets the user's todos here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-todos-deborahk-switchmap

```
this.todosForUser$ = this.http.get<User[]>(url)
  .pipe(
    switchMap(user =>
      this.http.get<ToDo[]>(`${this.todoUrl}?userId=${this.currentUserId}`)
    )
  );
```

Comment: I agree on the point of managing `unsubscribe`. At the same time, in my case the embedded subscription comes from a “just one shot” Observable, which completes as soon as its first notification gets fired. So unsubscription is not my problem. What I want to have is a logic that tries to send a mail and does not wait for any success or error notification. The use `switchMap` seems to imply that I have to wait for the reception of the response before completing the outer Observable, which is not what I want.